# How to apply CSS transformations on parent but not on child?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying make an isometric JavaScript game and I thought it would be nice to use CSS transformations for the grid.

```
   #grid {
      position: absolute;
      width: 800px;
      height: 800px;
      left: 400px;
      -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
    }
```

(see here for work so far: http://jsfiddle.net/8nydh/)

The images for the buildings however I don't want to transform.
Now I would like some advice on how to achieve this.

- Should I alter the structure so the tile is last descendant and the only transformed item? (making the setup slightly more complicated).
- Is there a way to "reset" CSS transformation on the child element (not counter transforming it!)
- Should I just draw the images over the grid by other means of positioning?
- Better ideas? Whole different technique/approach?

Answer (score 0):

you may apply exact opposite transformation to childs.
http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/ZfqfS/

```
transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(-15deg, -15deg);
```

back to

```
transform: rotate(45deg) skew( 0deg, 0deg);
```

Comment: I did that in my JFiddle example but how does this effect performance? Does it transform everything twice?

Comment: you could maybe put the child css before the parent in your style sheet, and just set the child classes to transform: rotate(0deg) skew(0deg,0ded); and then put the parent transform...it might work

Comment: No idea how much it affects performance, it only drawn to the screen

Answer (score 0):

I know its old question but this answer might help others.
For parent

```
#grid {
      position: absolute;
      width: 800px;
      height: 800px;
      left: 400px;
      -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
    }
```

For Child div

```
#child{     
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(-15deg, -15deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(-15deg, -15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(-15deg, -15deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg) skew(-15deg, -15deg);
    }
```

Comment: `transform: rotate(45deg) skew(0, 0);`